# Is it possible to create labels for the integers on custom properties?

Tags: properties

I'm creating a series of objects that have multiple interchangeable materials and node groups. Using the custom properties has been excellent for quickly changing elements on my objects but having ten custom properties with 20 integers can be a little confusing or random especially on small details. Is there a way to show names instead of numbers for example,

Laces > Red Laces / Blue Laces / Black Laces
rather than
Laces > 1 / 2 / 3...

I'm sure there some script but I actually have never scripted in Blender, I don't actually know where to implement it. If there is a non-scripting alternative that would be excellent.